# Simple client for file synchronization

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxpython, rsync, python-2.6

In my university project I need to write simple client for windows os, which will synchronize files in folder on PC (with windows OS) and server (Linux).

I decided to use python 2.6. And my question is which library should I use to implement rsync algorithm?

Or perhaps it is better to use c++ instead of python 2.6? Then which library should I use to implement rsync algorithm on c++?

It will be better if you can give me some examples or links. Because I couldn find anything in web.

Comment: why don't you just download rsync source code and study it?

Comment: Why you just dont ignoried this question? Ok you vote down and thats your right. Tell me why we need projects like stackoverflow. For example I can comment you guestion on gamedev.stackexchange: why don't you just download a game developement book and study it? Sometimes we need help. Thats normal. If you need vote down all my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some links that might help you:

- http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2010/05/12/smart-folder-synchronization-with-python/
- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/231501-python-robocopier-advanced-directory-synchronizati/
- http://fileconveyor.org/

Or you could just download an rsync client for Windows such as http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html and use Python's subprocess module to call it.